# Storing Date Components Instead of a Date

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, database-design, model

My app lets people log the movies they see (for example). Each logged movie usually (but not always) has a date and sometimes has a time. It's not unusual to have one but not the other. Occasionally the dates are only a year ("I watched a Dumbo sometime in 1984"), but could realistically be any combination of day/month/year/time.

I am used to modeling dates as date objects in my app and my backend. But is it a viable approach to store each component separately? When I need to reference an actual date from the components (e.g. for sorting the log) this will be built client-side, or perhaps be stored as a derived property `sortDate` and updated whenever any of the components change.

My reservation is that the information the user is saving is truly a 'moment in time' and I will have to take care of some things myself - for example what time zone are my components stored relative to? This would be captured automatically as part of a real Date object.

The alternative seems to be assuming some sort of 'default' for missing components (e.g. year 0000 if no year, time 00:00 if no time). But those defaults have meaning and I won't be able to distinguish them from 'not provided'.

What are the limitations and/or pitfalls of this approach? Does anyone have experience modeling their dates this way?

If it's of any consequence, my app is for iOS written in Swift and uses a Parse Server backend.

Comment: Not sure that's a good idea (IMHO).  It might be better to devise a series of structures which provide the functionality you need and which have the ability to provide either a `Date` value or (if your want) `DateComponents` or, probably better, some means of generating a presentable value (ie `String`)

Comment: I think that's what I'm proposing more or less - in iOS we have DateComponents which can optionally store any such component, or any can be nil. Let me know if I'm missing your point - wasn't 100% I understood 'series of structures' correctly.

Comment: IMHO, I'd avoid `DateComponents` as a "storage" mechanism, and rely instead of a one or more structs which can describe the data more reliably.  Such as "year", "date" and "date and time", around which you can make better, more, unambiguous decisions about - but that's just me

Comment: Ah, I'm using 'Date Components' to mean 'the components of the date' rather than `DateComponents` specifically. Yes a purpose built container might be the implementation.

Comment: Ah, sorry for my confusion 

Comment: `DateComponents` conforms to `Codable` related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023345/setting-datecomponents-array-to-userdefaults-not-working/57023513?r=SearchResults&s=1|120.2951#57023513

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, I'm good for the implementation details of storing the components, more interested in if it's a good idea from a model/design point of view or if people have experience doing so.

Answer (score -1):

I've successfully used question marks to represent ambiguous and unknown timestamp parts in legal systems. Try to keep in mind that you're really not modeling dates here ('1984' isn't a date); you're modeling facts about dates.

So, if one of your users saw a movie some time in 1984, you might record the value '1984-??-?? ??:??:??' in a text column in a database. Values like this sort sensibly.

[See also this answer on dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6066/1064). Comments on that answer are also good to read.

Comment: That's a great way of putting it - I'm not modeling a real date (a point in time). Thanks for the link. I'm testing a version right now using separate integer components since I don't display the stored values directly anyway - I will be displaying things like 'September 2000' if there is no day component.